# IndexOutOfRangeException (C#) on OleDBDataReader with SQL Count Function

Tags: c#, sql, count, oledb

Good afternoon,

I'm having a problem with a section of code I'm working on that checks to see if a dataitem of the same name already exists in a database.

The following code throws up an IndexOutOfRangeException

```
static int checkExists(String checkIf)
    {
        String connectionString = "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;data source=" + @"ffmpegDB.mdb";
        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();           

        try
        {
            command.CommandText = checkIf;

            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            reader.Read();
            try
            {
                result = (int)reader["Result"];
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException ioe) { }

            reader.Close();
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (FormatException Fe)
        {}

        return result;            
    }
```

..on this line

```
result = (int)reader["Result"];
```

The function is executed as follows:

```
if (checkExists("SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Result' FROM Files WHERE Filename ='"+fileNames[i]+"' AND File_Directory ='"+directories[i]+"'")==0)
```

{

}

etc..

Could this be a problem with OleDB and how it handles SQL statements?
Perhaps the reader is looking for the column 'Result' literally?

I hope I've provided enough information.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use,

```
result=(int)reader[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, have you tried using ExecuteScalar? Skips the whole data reader thing.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executescalar.aspx

```
object results = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

or

```
int results = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: Issue has been resolved but I have noted the link. Looks useful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just try doing following..

```
    if (checkExists("SELECT COUNT(*) AS Result FROM Files WHERE Filename ='"+fileNames[i]+"' AND File_Directory ='"+directories[i]+"'")==0);//
reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("Result"));
```

OR

```
    if (checkExists("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Files WHERE Filename ='"+fileNames[i]+"' AND File_Directory ='"+directories[i]+"'")==0); //
reader.GetInt32(0);// use this
```

Comment: Again, this works well. Proves that there are literally hundreds of ways to complete a process

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the SQL statement in a query analyzer?